# Formatting dates for Insert into MYSQL with Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am inserting data into MYSQL from node.js using node-mysql. I can insert data correctly via a MYSQL stored procedure call in Node except that my dates are always inserting as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

The date strings I am trying to insert are in the format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

I'm assuming I need to correctly format my dates in Node.js to insert?

```
connection.query('CALL sp_InsertUpdateOffer(' + NetworkID + ',"' + data["Promotion ID"] + '",' + data["Advertiser ID"] + ',"' + DataCleanUp(data.Description) + '",null,"' + DataCleanUp(data.Categories) + '","' + DataCleanUp(data.Code) + '","' + DataCleanUp(data.Terms.substring(0, 1000)) + '","' + data.Starts + '","' + data.Ends + '","' + DataCleanUp(data["Deeplink Tracking"]) + '","' + DataCleanUp(data.Deeplink) + '","' + DataCleanUp(data.Advertiser) + '")', function (err, rows, fields) {
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can re arrange your date format to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

If your date is in this format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`
do this to re arrange your date.

```
$date_select = "12/12/2016";
$newdate = explode("/",$date_select);
$final_date = $newdate[2]."-".$newdate[1]."-".$newdate[0];
```

now pass the `$final_date` to your insert query.

Comment: Thanks. I realised my source was in UK date format and the destination mysql was in US format. I followed the same as above but with split.

Comment: pleasure to help you.

Comment: OP asks for Node.js, not PHP.